# Does setAlternateIconName also changes app icon on Apple Watch companion app/Car play?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, carplay

I'm extending my app to have an ability to change app icons dynamically. I created a couple of new groups with new icons where I added all available resolutions(iPhones, iPads, watches and car play). But now I'm wondering will the call to `setAlternateIconName` also change the icon on the companion watch app or in the car play ? Or it only changes the icon on the device itself ? Didn't find this in documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it for one of my apps and can confirm that the alternative app icon shows up on CarPlay.